# Winform User Settings - Allow multiple choice values at Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, settings, propertygrid

I created a simple User Settings Dialog by binding the `Property.Settings` to a `PropertyGrid`.

This works like a charm but now I would like to allow only certain choices for some values.  I have noticed that some Types will give a **dropdown of possible choices**.  This is what I am shooting for but for, say, Strings.

Example, one of the *Settings* is *UserTheme* which is a String.  *Black*, *Blue*, *Silver*.  The program reads that string from the Settings File and sets the Theme on Startup.

I can type in a correct theme and it works but if I type in Pink it will not as there is not a pink option.

---

This is my VERY simple UserSettingsForm code.

```
    #region FIELDS

    internal Settings userSettings;

    #endregion

    #region EVENTS

    private void frmEditUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userSettings = Settings.Default;
        this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = userSettings;
        this.propertyGrid1.PropertySort = PropertySort.Alphabetical;
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userSettings.Save();
        //this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userSettings.Reload();
        this.Close();
    }

    #endregion
```

---

### EDIT

Okay, following the advice here I created a library file with my `enum` in it.  Referenced the `dll` in my main app.  Now in `settings` I see the `enum` but the `dropdown` only gives the first `enum` as an option.  Ideas?

```
namespace psWinForms
{
    public enum UserTheme
    {
        Blue,
        Black,
        Silver,
        Green,
        Pink
    };
}
```

Comment: It only shows the first option in the Designer but ALL options at runtime.  Not sure why but it is "working" now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual studio Settings editor shows a drop down automatically for enumeration types. You can try to create a UserTheme enumeration and test that the PropertyGrid behaves the sames as the Visual Studio Settings editor.

```
public enum UserTheme
{
    Black,
    Blue,
    Silver
}
```

---

**Update:** I just tested and `PropertyGrid` automatically shows a drop down for an enumeration type.

Comment: Nice.  I will give that a look.  Any guesses on WHERE to create that `enumeration` so that it'll be picked up?

Comment: @Refracted Paladin, IIRC when you choose the type of a setting you are allowed to browse into referenced assemblies. So placing your public enumeration in a library should work.

Comment: @Joao Angelo: So you are right, in, that Enums is the way to go.  Unfortunately I cannot get it to show in the settings.  See my edit for details.

Comment: @Refracted Paladin, do not nest the enumeration type inside a class. I never tried that and don't know if the Settings designer supports that in any way.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a TypeConverter class. (System.ComponentModel)
You can then associate a class with a Typeconverter via an attribute. (Even a property if I am not mistaken)

The methods you need to implement then are the GetStandardValues and related methods.

There is much documentation available on the net.